# matMenu breaking when using a method in ngFor

Tags: angular

When using the mat menu inside a ngFor loop with a method getGroupedFiles() like this

```
<tr *ngFor="let a of getGroupedFiles()">
    <td class="options-menu" [matMenuTriggerFor]="fileoptions"><button> <img src="/assets/dots.svg" alt="options"> </button></td>
    <mat-menu #fileoptions="matMenu">
        <button mat-menu-item>Delete</button>
    </mat-menu>
</tr>
```

it breaks the menu. Trying to click on the button simply does nothing. No errors but cdk-overlay-container does not get created.

After some testing I've determined the problem is the method but I don't understand why.

This doesn't work.

```
getGroupedFiles(): KeyValue<string, ApiFile[]>[] {
        const groupedMap = new Map<string, ApiFile[]>();

        this.files.files.forEach((item) => {
            const key = item.key;
            if (!groupedMap.has(key)) {
                groupedMap.set(key, []);
            }
            groupedMap.get(key)!.push(item);
        });

        return Array.from(groupedMap.entries()).map(([key, value]) => ({
            key,
            value,
        }));
    }
```

But this one does (I've saved the result of the previous one in a variable).

```
getGroupedFiles(): KeyValue<string, ApiFile[]>[] {
    return this.groupedFiles;
}
```

The second example is my solution but I'd like to understand why the first example doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it does not matter if the function has errors or not!

Function calls in template are just bad: they will trigger Change Detection too many times, risking to glitch the app!

Just avoid them! You can adopt smarter strategies (pure pipes, observables, computer properties, signals...)